# React-Bootstrap variable number of Cols per Row based on breakpoint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Currently I have this code:

```
return(
<Container>
    {array.map(function(item, i) {
        if (i%4 == 0) {
            return(
                <Row key={i} xs="3" sm="4">
                {array.slice(i, i+4).map(function(item, i) {
                    return(
                    <Col key={i}>
                        <Card className={"card"}>
                            <Card.Body>
                            <Card.Text>{item.name}</Card.Text>
                            </Card.Body>
                        </Card>
                    </Col>);
                })}
                </Row>
            );
        }
    })}
</Container>);
```

To give some context - I am pulling a variable amount of data from a database into an *array*, and displaying them as cards. I am using a *Container* to display it in a Grid, consisting of *x* rows and *y* columns. However, for any screens larger than the xs breakpoint, I would like to display *4* items per *Row*, hence *4 Cols* per *Row*. Once the xs breakpoint is hit, I would like to display *3* items per *Row*. However, the functionality right now isn't as I intended. Consider the following example:

```
A B C D
E F G H
```

becomes

```
A B C
D
E F G
H
```

instead of

```
A B C
D E F
G H
```

Would anyone be able to advise where or how I can get this fixed? In my search through the docs and online, I could not find any example which has a similar use-case (or maybe I'm not searching for the correct term). Any help would be great, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably happening because you are using `array.slice(i, i+4)` and the function is taking 4 elements at a time.

You may rather try :

```
return(
  <Container>
    <Row key={i} xs="3" sm="4">
      {array.map(function(item, i) {
        return(
          <Col key={i}>
              <Card className={"card"}>
                  <Card.Body>
                  <Card.Text>{item.name}</Card.Text>
                  </Card.Body>
              </Card>
          </Col>
        );
        })}
    </Row>
  </Container>);
```

Hopefully this will work (maybe a bit more manipulation).

Comment: Oh, thank you! I was under the impression that I had to initially force the creation of a new Row every 4 items, I was not aware that I could accomplish the same by rendering all the Cols within 1 Row, and then just restricting the number of Cols in a Row based on the breakpoint, had no idea the library was able to account for that.